# New badge for top contributor

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I recently received an automated (?) email from SuperUser I think saying well done on posting so many answers, I was a top contributor for that week. This has nothing to do with getting over 200 points on a day directly.

I think this should be a badge for this. Get 1 for bronze, 10 for silver, 50 for Gold (or whatever you feel).

Comment: In reality this would be very similar to the Epic and Legendary badges, but instead limited to an absolute number of people regardless of how large the site is; I don't think that's a particularly good thing

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you think it would be limited. Getting to be the top *anything* is no easy task and should be recognized.

Comment: It is recognized, you got an email.